# Ubuntu 13.10 continuous beeping

Tags: boot, grub2, sound, hardware

I'm using Ubuntu 13.1064b on a Dell Inspiron N5010.

Sometimes when I boot into Ubuntu, I get a continuous beeping noise on my sound card output. My laptop's internal speakers stopped working a long time ago, so I have no way of confirming if it's an issue with the audio output.

This noise starts only after Ubuntu boots, for I can hear it only after I select Ubuntu from the GRUB.

Shutting down the system and rebooting once works sometimes, but other times it takes multiple reboots for the beeping to stop.

I'm a real beginner. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: This is a strange problem.  I would start by looking through the kernel logs for any errors or warnings.  Also google for your laptop model and see if other people have had similar problems.  How old is this laptop?  I guess it's unlikely, but this could be a case of a Linux driver accessing non-conforming hardware differently than Windows (or an older Linux driver) and the hardware behaving strangely.  If so, it's possible that upgrading to 14.04 will fix it.

Comment: Have you had any problems with sticky keys?   Might be a "buffer full" warning.  Can you still type things when the sound is occurring?

Comment: @blujay the kernel log has a lot of information. I am not able to filter out any issues.

Comment: @ubfan1 I will check it the next time this problem occurs

Comment: It would be good to post info about your laptop's hardware, chipset, audio chipset, etc, for future reference.

Comment: how would I get this info on Ubuntu 13.10?